TCL error : "extra characters after close-quote" when putting HTML code inside tcl
I got on error message
extra characters after close-quote
   while compiling
"puts $o "
                <TR>
                    <TD align=\"center\" BGCOLOR = \"FFFFFF\" ><FONT COLOR =
\"black\">$rulename</FONT></TD>
                    <TD align=\"left\" BGCOLOR = \"F..."
    ("if" then script line 28)


This is occured after I put in this code below
<input type ="radio" value ="clear" name ="clear_waive">clear
<input type ="radio" value ="clear" name ="clear_waive">waive &nbsp


I want to put a radio button in the excel chart that is formed by above whole HTML code in tcl,
and it worked where I tried at the "HTML code test website" but it didn't in the tcl code.
I tried to test the 'radio button' code in HTML TEST website(AKA liveweave.com) and it worked properly.
However it didn't when I put the same code in tcl.
I only want the code to display the radio button on the excel chart the same as HTML test website.

You have a formal syntax error somewhere, most likely a missing backslash in front of a double quote character. Syntax highlighting in your code editor can reveal the likely location fairly easily.
You might be better off using a construction like this:
puts $o [subst {
    <TR>
        <TD align="center" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">
            <FONT COLOR="black">$rulename</FONT>
        </TD>
    ...
}]

Like this, the contents of the braces are an HTML fragment and follow the syntax rules for that except for the Tcl substitutions within it. This is much easier to write (and read!) than putting lots of backslashes in a double-quoted string.

When doing this you should be aware that substituted variables (and command results) are interpreted as HTML fragments; critical entity escaping may be required. Or maybe not; that could be what you want; you do need to be aware of it however. The string map command can do such substitutions; put it in a mnemonic procedure for ease of use.
